# What happened to the option to cross your eyes whilst watching YouTube?

Tags: youtube, 3d

[Certain YouTube Videos are 3D.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0U0ZDjnQiXQ) Note that there is a "3D" symbol next to the gear, denoting the YouTube is in fact storing the video in a 3D format.

Right now, I see only two options: 2D, and Anaglyph. I remember in the past there was an option to cross eyes to make the video 3D.

Is there a way to restore this option?

Edit: Here is a video [documenting the feature](https://youtu.be/pNuKAaC337U?t=32s) before it was removed.